# SQL Server 2016 UPDATE statement - are variable assignments always processed before column updates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

One of our application devs came to me with an interesting question. In the following code, you'll see that the update statement is assigning the current column values to two variables, but also updating those same columns to new values.

The question was, is it **guaranteed** that the variables @oStart and @oFinish will be assigned to the *old* values of [Start] and [Finish] and not the *new* values? Under testing, this has been the case, however, I'd like to confirm this is the guaranteed behaviour.

I expect the answer is "no - it's not guaranteed", and ultimately, it's down to the decision the optimiser takes. Regardless, this kind of ambiguous code is to be discouraged anyway (there are more elegant and readable ways of writing it), but would be interested to hear everyone's thoughts.

```
-- Parameters
DECLARE @StartDate smalldatetime = '2022-01-01',
       @EndDate smalldatetime = '2022-12-31';

-- Body
DECLARE @oStart smalldatetime,
       @oFinish smalldatetime;

UPDATE  [dbo].[MyTable]
SET     @oStart = [Start],
       @oFinish = [Finish],
       [Start] = @StartDate,
       [Finish] = @EndDate
WHERE   [ID] = 12;
```

Comment: If you've never seen it, the standard way to swap the contents of two columns in SQL is `UPDATE tab SET a=b, b=a`, precisely because the right hand sides are effectively computed before any assignments take place.

Comment: FWIW, those date literals are wrong for SQL Server. If you have a date-only value, with no time component, you should omit the hyphens: `20220101` and `20221231`. Additionally, for a full-year range like that, you want to define it using **exclusive** upper bound for the range for **the day after**. That said, this tends to confuse lay people who do data entry for the ranges, so it's also common to do the check for the upper range for the day after the stored value :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this is documented. See the documentation for [`@variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=SET%20%40variable%20%3D%20column%2C%20column%20%3D%20expression%2C%20which%20sets%20the%20variable%20to%20the%20pre%2Dupdate%20value%20of%20the%20column) in the `UPDATE` syntax.

> `SET @variable = column` ... sets the variable to the pre-update value
> of the column.

(As contrasted in the documentation to `SET @variable = column = expression` which will set the variable to the value **after** the `column = expression` assignment).

```
DECLARE @oldStart  SMALLDATETIME,
        @oldFinish SMALLDATETIME,
        @newStart  SMALLDATETIME,
        @newFinish SMALLDATETIME;

DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
  (
     ID     INT PRIMARY KEY,
     Start  SMALLDATETIME,
     Finish SMALLDATETIME
  )

INSERT @MyTable
VALUES(12, '1900-01-01', '1900-01-31');

UPDATE @MyTable
SET    @oldStart = [Start],
       @oldFinish = [Finish],
       @newStart = [Start] = '2022-01-01',
       @newFinish = [Finish] = '2022-12-31'
WHERE  [ID] = 12;

SELECT @oldStart  AS [@oldStart],
       @oldFinish AS [@oldFinish],
       @newStart  AS [@newStart],
       @newFinish AS [@newFinish];
```

Returns

| @oldStart | @oldFinish | @newStart | @newFinish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1900-01-01 00:00:00 | 1900-01-31 00:00:00 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00 |

Assuming `ID` is the primary key so the `UPDATE` is guaranteed to affect at most one row then personally I think this syntax is fine if you need to assign that value to a SQL variable.

It beats having to use the `OUTPUT ... INTO` clause to store these values somewhere and then a subsequent `SELECT` from that to assign to the variable.

Answer (score 5):

The SQL standard stipulates that

> The <update source> of each <set clause> contained in SCL [Set Clause List] is effectively evaluated for each row of [table] T **before any row of T is updated**

(emphasis mine). In your case it means that, according to the standard, `@oStart` and `@oFinish` must have the values of `[Start]` and `[Finish]`, respectively, as they exist *before* the update.

Now, whether SQL Server complies with the standard in this regard is a different question.

Comment: SQL Server does follow the standard here.